# Database or List of English First and Last Names

Tags: resources, datasource

I've come across a few smaller lists/sets of names but I was wondering if there is a free data source out there that can provide a list of names (comma delimited or in a sql structure)?

I've found these two sites:

http://names.mongabay.com/most_common_surnames.htm

http://baby-names.familyeducation.com/browse/letter/a?detoured=1

However it seems you can only browse the names, not download a comprehensive file.

Doesn't the US Census Bureau provide this information?

Answer (score 41):

I'm compiling a database that contains last names from a variety of different countries and cultures, the UK among them. <s>The project and its datasets can be found here: https://github.com/enorvelle/NameDatabases</s><sup>(Dead: link, project and GitHub account)</sup>

**This seems to have migrated to [github.com/smashew/NameDatabases](https://github.com/smashew/NameDatabases).** (Sole contributer "Erik Norvelle".)

Comment: This seems not to be available more.

Comment: @BorisD.Teoharov, link updated.

Answer (score 10):

The best source I have been able to find on this is the data provided by the social security administration - unlike the census data, they have first names for every year going back to ~1900.

https://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/limits.html

Answer (score 8):

The Census Bureau provides list of common surnames from the 2000 and 1990 censuses: 
http://www.census.gov/topics/population/genealogy/data/2000_surnames.html
http://www.census.gov/topics/population/genealogy/data/1990_census/1990_census_namefiles.html

The 1990 census files also have lists of common male and female names.

Answer (score 6):

**Option 1)**
 I uploaded Millions of people data into github  which I crawled from different website and dumped from Google open dataset.

https://github.com/aakashkag/People-Name-List [Github Link for First and last name directory]

**Option 2)**

Google BigQuery Public Dataset:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/

You can get names from Google open dataset along with gender.

1)Dataset: bigquery-public-data:github_repos

Example: https://app.hyfy.io/v/abRJ75Xizno/

Query:SELECT  * FROM `fh-bigquery.popular_names.usa_summary_1880_2015` LIMIT 1000 
Total Names availble : 1858689

2)Dateset: bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits

Query: SELECT author.name as author_name, author.email as author_email, committer.name as committer_name, committer.email as committer_email, repo_name FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits`

3)Dateset: bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013`

Query: SELECT  * FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013`

Or you can get from Linkdin
https://www.linkedin.com/directory/people-a

Comment: Looks cool, but could you include more information about the source of the data? I am not sure what countries and languages this applies to, or where the data comes from.

Comment: The "First Names" file is all but useless, unfortunately. Looks more like usernames rather than first names.

Comment: @CodeBling Updated My answer also updated Dataset

Comment: @AakashKag what is the source of the data?

Comment: This repository is using Git Large File Storage, which has a 1GB bandwidth quota for free accounts.