# List of all names in the world

Tags: arrays

Does anyone know where to get a list of all the names in the world? I'm looking for at least 1 million+ names.

I tried dozens of sites, but some has too little, and some like - https://forebears.io/ has, I suppose hidden source of names.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: FOUND - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391799/database-or-list-of-english-first-and-last-names

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Database or List of English First and Last Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391799/database-or-list-of-english-first-and-last-names)

Comment: @Rafi Yes, already found this, thank you!